# OpenCV findDataMatrix

Tags: c++, opencv

while i was compiling several opencv-cpp-examples,

i found two errors about DataMatrix

> error: ‘findDataMatrix’ was not declared in this scope 
> error:
>   ‘drawDataMatrixCodes’ was not declared in this scope

i looked up objdetect.hpp but i couldn't find out what's wrong.
i use ubuntu 15.10 & openCV 3.0.0

sample codes are :

```
Mat frame;
capture >> frame;
if (frame.empty())
    break;
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(frame,gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
vector<string> codes;
Mat corners;
findDataMatrix(gray, codes, corners);
drawDataMatrixCodes(frame, codes, corners);
imshow(window_name, frame);
```

Comment: Which samples are you referring to? Those functions are gone in OpenCV 3.0

Comment: i was using samples from https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/video_dmtx.cpp

Comment: in that case is there any alteration for those functions?
And which version has those functions?